# Abrir popups en todas la paginas solo una vez

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

tengo un modal sencillo

```
<div id="newsletter-modal" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true " tabindex="-1 " role="dialog " aria-labelledby="">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document ">
        <div class="modal-content ">

            <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>-->

            <div class="newsletter-wrapper ">
                <img src="/arquivos/POP-SPRIMG-JULIO-18.jpg"/>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix "></div>
        </div>
        <!--.modal-content-->
    </div>
    <!--.modal-dialog-->
</div>
```

para abrirlo en automáticamente al cargar la pagina uso esto

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#newsletter-modal').modal('toggle')
    });
</script>
```

lo que quiero hacer ahora es que se cargue en todas la paginas es decir si entran a esta url www.sitio.com/producto o al home se cargue el popup, pero que solo se muestre una vez, pero no se como hacerlo.

gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un archivo javascript por ejemplo modal_inicial.js; en ese archivo ingresar tu código:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#newsletter-modal').modal('toggle')
    });
```

Y en cada vista que desees que se abra el modal referencias al archivo

```
<script src="modal_inicial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: me funciono, como configuro para se cargue solo una vez, es decir al recargar la pag no se vuela a abrir? o donde puedo ver ejemplos ya busque pero no encuentro nda